# vue vite dynamic components import

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

I am migrating an existing laravel ineria from mix to vit.

I did all the steps in the migration guid and everything works fine except for one thing.

I have a component receives a prop conatains an array of components.

I used to require them like this (inside a loop)

```
...

this.$options.components[component_name] = require(`@/Pages/Components/Inputs/${component_name}`).default

...
```

this wont work with vite because of "**require**", I have to replace it with **import**

so I tried these ways and none of them works

```
this.$options.components[component_name] = () => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/Components/Inputs/${component_name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'))


this.$options.components[component_name] = () => resolvePageComponent(`@/Pages/Components/Inputs/${component_name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'))

this.$options.components[component_name] = resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/Components/Inputs/${component_name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'))

this.$options.components[component_name] = resolvePageComponent(`@/Pages/Components/Inputs/${component_name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue'))
```

all of them throws the same exception

```
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Page not found: ./Pages/Components/Inputs/Text.vue".
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: unfortunately no,
I can not move to vite untill this problem solved.

Comment: whenever I solve it, I will answer the question here.

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 checkout the answer to this question if you still need it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, this is how I solved it.

you need to import this

```
import {defineAsyncComponent} from "vue";
```

on the data, defin this is an empty array

```
layout_components: []
```

on the created or mounted you need to define this

```
mounted() {
    this.layout_components = Object.keys(this.$options.components)
    this.layouts.forEach(layout => this.importLayoutComponent(layout))
}
```

this will get the componsents you are using and add them to an array

finally,

I created this method to import the components dynamicly

```
importLayoutComponent(layout) {
    if (!this.layout_components.includes(layout.name)) {
        this.layout_components.push(layout.name)
        this.$options.components[layout.name] = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`../Sections/${layout.type}/${layout.name}.vue`))
    }
}
```

in my html template

```
<component
  :is="layout.name"
  ... //other propes to pass to the component
/>
```

**NOTE: you need to write the path to the component like this "../path-to-component"**