# Laravel Vue3 and Vite Rollups - Fails dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, laravel-9, inertiajs

I've been spending some time rewriting an application to Laravel 9 with Inertia, Vite, Vue3 Composition API, and Typescript.

Everything went good and when I tested the production build on my local environment by running `npm run build` everything bundled up for production and looked fine.

Now I've launched the new codebase, and half of the web page is not working.. why is that? Because Vite can't resolve my dynamic imports.

I don't get the difference between `npm run build` on my local (which works) from the live site `npm run build`... I know `npm run dev` uses es6bundling while the `npm run build` uses rollup.

I have a very basic setup like this, `currentHeader` is the dynamic component:

```
<template>
    <component
        :is="currentHeader"
    />
</template>
```

I've tried several different approaches, but nothing works. *It only works when I hardcode the string path* which prevents me from making it dynamic

**1 -** I changed all my paths from using @/ to using direct paths

**2 -** I Tried to add the path of the dynamic import to the `vite.config.js`

```
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        external: [
            "./components/HeaderStandard.vue",
            "resources/js/Components/BitHeader/components/HeaderStandard.vue",
        ]
    }
}
```

**3 -** I've tried to load the header with `defineAsyncComponent` like this:

```
let headers = {
    secondary: './components/HeaderSecondary.vue',
    standard: './components/HeaderStandard.vue'
}
const headerPath = shallowRef<string>(headers.default);
const currentHeader = defineAsyncComponent(() => import(headerPath .value));
```

**4 -** I've tried to load the header with a chain...

```
let headers = {
    secondary: './components/HeaderSecondary.vue',
    standard: './components/HeaderStandard.vue'
}
const headerPath = shallowRef<string>(headers.default);

function importHeader(){
    import(headerPath.default).then(val => {
        currentHeader.value = val.default;
    });
}
```

I have tried several other solutions, but nothing worked out

There are other questions out there, but none has solved my problem

I have also checked out a [package](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations) from rollup which should have helped but didn't work either. When I add `dynamicImportVars` to the `vite.config.js` under plugins the whole page crashes, I assume that the `include` key is default *all* as it says so in the documentation.

**Resources**

1 - I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009814/vue-vite-rollup-dynamic-import-not-working-on-production-build) question which has 1k views in 3 months and no upvotes, so people still need answers.

2 - I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73096758/vue-vite-dynamic-components-import) question which has no answers and 3 upvotes

3 - I've been looking at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-dynamic-imports?file=src%2Frouter.ts) and [this](https://www.angularfix.com/2022/02/vite-vue-router-dynamic-imports.html) which looked promising, but I could not get it to work.

The error is something along these lines:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module
```

Does anyone know an answer to this?

Comment: "I changed all my paths from using @/ to using direct paths as stated in the documentation" According to which documentation? I feel like you might be combining solutions from different resources, which messes things up for you. Stay with one and you should be fine.

Comment: I have the same issue, any solutions? Inertia fails to load module.